# Redux-saga call multiple functions/actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I want to call two different functions in my sagas with different actions:

```js
export default function* () {
  yield takeLatest(actionTypes.ADD_ACCOUNT, addAccountSaga);
  yield takeLatest(actionTypes.GET_WALLET, getBalanceSaga);
}
```

I've read some articles and I tried to put them in array like this :

```js
yield [(
  takeLatest(actionTypes.ADD_ACCOUNT, addAccountSaga), 
  takeLatest(actionTypes.GET_WALLET, getBalanceSaga)
)];
```

But sadly it did not work, I also tried this method:

```js
yield * takeLatest(actionTypes.ADD_ACCOUNT, addAccountSaga);
yield * takeLatest(actionTypes.GET_WALLET, getBalanceSaga);
```

I also putted console.log in one of the functions to be sure if its working or not but console.log did not worked which means function is not being called

But this also did not work. Could you help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`all` effect combinator](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#alleffects---parallel-effects)

> Creates an Effect description that instructs the middleware to run multiple Effects in parallel and wait for all of them to complete

```
yield all([
  takeLatest(actionTypes.ADD_ACCOUNT, addAccountSaga), 
  takeLatest(actionTypes.GET_WALLET, getBalanceSaga)
])
```

Answer (score 0):

for multiple in one file you have to do something like following:

```
export function* getShirtPlans() {
  try {
    const response = yield call(API.apiGetShirtPlans);
    yield put(ACTIONS.setShirtPlans(response.data.data.intervals));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

export function* getShirtStyles() {
  try {
    const response = yield call(API.apiGetShirtStyles);
    console.log(response.data.data);
    yield put(ACTIONS.setShirtStyles(response.data.data));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

export function* watchOngetShirtPlans() {
  yield takeLatest(TYPES.GET_SHIRTS_PLANS, getShirtPlans);
}

export function* watchOngetShirtStyles() {
  yield takeLatest(TYPES.GET_SHIRTS_STYLES, getShirtStyles);
}
```

and in main saga index file import like that:

```
import { fork, all } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { watchOngetShirtPlans, watchOngetShirtStyles } from "../sagas/ShirtsSaga";

export function* watchSagas() {
  yield all([
    fork(watchOngetShirtPlans),
    fork(watchOngetShirtStyles)
  ]);
}
```